# iOS & OpenCV : debug malloc_error_break on device

Tags: objective-c, ios, opencv, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I got this error when using my app (under ARC)

```
(816,0x2ffe0000) malloc: *** error for object 0xb185010: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

So I set a malloc_error_break breakpoint and did not get any additional information to the console.
I add **bt** to the console and get

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x3635117c in malloc_error_break ()
#1  0x362dd924 in free ()
#2  0x31d64588 in -[NSConcreteData dealloc] ()
#3  0x319a50c4 in _objc_rootRelease ()
#4  0x319a6db6 in objc_release ()
#5  0x319a5e0c in (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop ()
#6  0x319a5d28 in _objc_autoreleasePoolPop ()
#7  0x37e13e8e in _CFAutoreleasePoolPop ()
#8  0x37b818e6 in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#9  0x362e61ce in _pthread_wqthread ()
#10 0x362e60a4 in start_wqthread ()
```

The error appears at different time, different usage and I cannot find the code involve.
Any idea how to debug (only on device, I use AVCaptureSession).

### Edit

I think it comes from

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:cvMat.data
                                    length:(cvMat.elemSize() * cvMat.total())
                              freeWhenDone:YES];

CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);
```

With this code, I constraint memory allocation

[Instruments With No Copy](http://s14.postimage.org/wq2zr6j0x/Capture_d_cran_2012_03_16_18_30_53.png)

Whereas if I change it to

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data
                                  length:(cvMat.elemSize() * cvMat.total())];
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);
```

I got something strange which looks like an AutoReleasePool

[Instruments With Copy](http://s18.postimage.org/93o2x0yrd/Capture_d_cran_2012_03_16_18_31_11.png)

Could the error be due to autoreleasing of one of the object in the code ?

*method taken from Robin Summerhill

Comment: I think it is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257435/how-to-resolve-malloc-error-break-xcode-objective-c and http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/40661-set-breakpoint-malloc_error_break-debug.html

Comment: Already look at these links. malloc_error_break and NSZombies do not work on device unfortunately !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cyberserker,

Your data is being deallocated by the autorelease pool drain. `CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData()` does not appear to retain your data item. The easiest way to change this behavior is to use the init form to create `data`. As in:

```
int *dataBytes = malloc(20);
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:dataBytes
                                            length:20
                                      freeWhenDone:YES];

CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge_retained CFDataRef)data);
```

When you finally release `provider`, you may also have to release the `CFData` (but I doubt it).

Andrew

Comment: @adonho. I tried your solution and it seems it does not call autorelease pool anymore. What I do not understand is why under ARC this factory methods return an object that goes inside an autoreleasepool ? I do not release CFData (complaint from Analyser if I do it) but the app continue to crash. Always under investigation...

Comment: cyberserker, ARC does not change the retention rules for returned objects. Most objects in Cocoa are still autoreleased and not ARC released. W.r.t. your crash, I assume the autorelease trace above is now invalid. Where is it exactly crashing? Where exactly do you release `provider`? Andrew

Comment: @adonho.
Thank you for these informations about ARC. I have to update a lot of my code since I was using mainly factories since ARC!

I have updated Xcode to 4.3.1 and now use LLDB.
Now, the analyzer says that I have to release data ?
It is what I did:
`CFDataRef dataRef = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)data;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(dataRef);
CFRelease(dataRef);`

And now all seems to work (need to do a long run to be sure).
I will probably never understand what was the problem (Xcode 4.2, GCD, me ?).I'd like to add a vote to you but I cannot currently, sorry.