# Mac OS X Terminal app broken after failed Yosemite update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to rebuild my RVM/Rails environment after a failed update to Yosemite. TimeMachine failed on restoring my system to 10.9.5 and my account settings. In the process, Terminal is no longer working, so I can't install RVM or Rails. It also broke my Posgress.app install. Anyway, this is the error message I get when I launch Terminal.

---

login(307,0x7fff73545310) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f81c9415320: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

[Process was terminated by signal 6]

---

I've tried restoring the defaults in the Preferences view. My old .bash_profile is the same but fails. I've removed my .bash_profile and it still fails. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to question: Found another post using different search terms.

[Mac Terminal - 'pointer being freed was not allocated' error when opening terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329005/mac-terminal-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-error-when-opening-termin)