# Mac Terminal - 'pointer being freed was not allocated' error when opening terminal or tab

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-mavericks

I am getting the following error when I open a new window in the terminal
~/.bash_profile
-bash(74540,0x7fff7e1d0300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fa5b9f1c5a0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I have already tried the steps in [Mac Terminal - 'pointer being freed was not allocated' error when opening terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329005/mac-terminal-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-error-when-opening-termin) 
but it has not solved my problem.I am using OSX Mavericks