# Terminal Mac OSX showing Process Completed Error when I start it. How do I get the normal bash back?

Tags: macos, terminal

Terminal Mac OSX is showing Process Completed Error when I start it. The last operation I did was to change the file permissions of some directories when trying to install rails. How do I get the normal bash back?

> login(4983,0x7fff78360300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff132c024c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>
> [Process completed]

[image: Problem with mac terminal]

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329005/mac-terminal-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-error-when-opening-termin?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac Terminal - 'pointer being freed was not allocated' error when opening terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329005/mac-terminal-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-error-when-opening-termin)