# Python 3.6.2 installed with macport giving crashes when using from terminal

Tags: python, macports, python-3.6

Upgraded my OS X to mac sierra ad updated macport (`sudo port selfupdate`). Then tried to run python from terminal and getting this error every time:

```
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 18 2017, 14:08:57) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
Python(1316,0x7fffee2213c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x105b21698: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I installed `py36-readline` but it didn't help. How to fix this now?

I found this on GitHub: [Crashes with Python 3.6 - MacOS Sierra](https://github.com/ludwigschwardt/python-gnureadline/issues/50), but did no help.

Comment: Is this relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329005/mac-terminal-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-error-when-opening-termin It would seem that this is a problem in general with executables in OSX

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen; Nope! I am not getting error while opening terminal. I get it only when I launch `python3` from the terminal.

Comment: I've got no issues with python 3.6.2 from Homebrew, so it looks a macport issue to me. Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling python instead of just upgrading? And make sure your symlinks are pointing to the new binary? * edit oops sorry, i'm not on Sierra but on El capitan. Not sure if that matters

Comment: @IrmendeJong; Already uninstalled and reinstalled it few times. Didn't work. I came here after I exhausted trying every possible solution came to my mind.

Comment: @IrmendeJong; I found the solution. You were right. It's macports problem.

Comment: can you contact me at my email in profile. Thanks

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; Hi Grijesh. After long time :). Will do sure. Can you just give me a little brief for the purpose of contact?

Comment: @haccks help on C internals work. wil answer you back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! 
Its macports problem as pointed by [Irmen de Jong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4451406/irmen-de-jong) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805737/python-3-6-2-giving-error-when-using-from-terminal#comment78569770_45805737). Installing `py36-readline` will not solve the problem as it says in the message after installing `python36`

```
##############################################################
# IF YOU ARE USING PYTHON FROM THE TERMINAL, PLEASE INSTALL:
#   py36-readline
# TO AVOID A LIBEDIT / PYTHON INTERACTION ISSUE.
# REF: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/48807
##############################################################
```

Solution is given at the [REF](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/48807) link.
Do the following:

- Remove python36: `sudo port uninstall python36`
- Remove py36-readline: `sudo port uninstall py36-readline`
- Install python36 with `sudo port install python36 +readline`

This will fix the error.