# Django: why am i getting malloc?

Tags: python, macos, malloc

I am new to Django and getting below error in a simple todo app that i trying to create.

I am not sure what is causing it. I only added one app of 'todos' and when i go to admin page i get this error below on pycharm running on MacOS.

> ```
> [21/Dec/2018 06:58:05] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3042
> Python(1756,0x700009e06000) malloc: *** error for object 0x1015c6ae4: pointer being freed was not allocated
> set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
> Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
> ```

Below is some part of the crash report that i get.

**Process:               Python [1151]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.7.0 (3.7.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Python [1150]
Responsible:           Python [1151]
User ID:               501
Process:               Python [1151]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.7.0 (3.7.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Python [1150]
Responsible:           Python [1151]
User ID:               501**

Comment: What version of django are you using, did you try updating it. And if still causing issue, Try creating a virtualenv and reinstall all the dependencies.

Comment: i am using 2.1.4

Comment: Try creating a virutalenv and then try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac Terminal - 'pointer being freed was not allocated' error when opening terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329005/mac-terminal-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-error-when-opening-termin)

Comment: Django is pure python code, and this is a problem in a C lib, so it has nothing to do with Django actually.

Comment: I tried onyx as mentioned in the other post but it still isn't working for me. I reset the permissions of /usr/bin/ using command diskutil command and it did but no luck. I am running on High Sierra OS

Answer (score -1):

you don't have the right permissions on `/usr/bin` directory some how!

I've seen a similar post like this on stack overflow. [(Mac Terminal - 'pointer being freed was not allocated' error when opening terminal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329005/mac-terminal-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-error-when-opening-termin)

This post will guide you how to fix this permission problem.

Comment: i tried but no help. i am getting below crash report. see if you can help here or no.
Process:               Python [1151]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python